# Using the whole dataset for testing (not validation) in case of small datasets

Tags: dataset, feature-selection, object-detection, validation

for an object detection task I created a small dataset to train an object detector. The class frequency is more or less balanced, however I defined some additional attributes with environmental conditions for each image, which results in a rather uneven distribution of classes depending on the viewed attribute (e.g. class X occurring with attributes A and B).

I used a typical training/validation split and the loss curve lets me conclude that no over-fitting is occurring. I am aware that in general for testing unseen images with a realistic feature distribution should be used, however due to the small size of the dataset, splitting off additional 10 or 20 % for testing or randomly drawing examples would result in certain combinations of classes and attributes not or only barely occurring in the test dataset and manually selecting examples would be very time-consuming.

I am therefore now wondering, if it reasonable to use the whole dataset (train+val) for testing and calculation of performance metrics as a compromise since I see no signs over-fitting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you have not used a cross-validation strategy, you could try to use the LOOCV ([Leave One Out Cross Validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html)) strategy, so you have several splits (as many as samples considered in your training dataset) and still leave some samples as a final never-seen-before validation set.

This is costly from a performance perspective, but interesting for small datasets as in your case. Another option, in case the dataset is not really small, is usin k-fold cross-validation (with k being 5, 10...).

A post with practical info can be found [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/loocv-for-evaluating-machine-learning-algorithms/) and a related topic discussion can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What-is-leave-one-out-cross-validation-How-can-I-use-it-for-image-fusion)

Comment: Mmm that would require to train N models if I have N images right? Since I have 4500 images, this is out of a computational feasible range for me. But maybe a 5-fold cross validation could be sufficient.

Comment: of course, k-fold cross-validation is the best option (k=5 or 10 usually), I thought your dataset was even smaller

Comment: Yea, I should have added that info earlier. I will enlarge my validation set and use cross validation and rather sacrifice on performance instead scientific principles. Thanks!